# OpenStack OpenContrail Horizon Login Error

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, horizon

Hello i am a newbie working with OpenStack, i have installed openstack + opencontrail by following (Single Node setup):

http://www.opencontrail.org/opencontrail-quick-start-guide/

Opencontrail loads fine (WebConsole), but when i launch horizon web console, i see "Something went wrong" error

I have read other question with the same error but the cause it is different
"NeutronClientException:

## 503 Service Unavailable

[Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error] No server is available to handle this request.
"

Can you help me please?

This is the log message :

> Internal Server Error: /horizon/admin/
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/decorators.py", line 38, in dec
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/decorators.py", line 86, in dec
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/decorators.py", line 54, in dec
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/decorators.py", line 38, in dec
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/decorators.py", line 86, in dec
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 87, in dispatch
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/tables/views.py", line 154, in get
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     handled = self.construct_tables()
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/tables/views.py", line 145, in construct_tables
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     handled = self.handle_table(table)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/tables/views.py", line 118, in handle_table
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     data = self._get_data_dict()
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/tables/views.py", line 181, in _get_data_dict
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     self._data = {self.table_class._meta.name: self.get_data()}
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/dashboards/admin/overview/views.py", line 60, in get_data
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     data = super(GlobalOverview, self).get_data()
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/usage/views.py", line 44, in get_data
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     self.usage.get_limits()
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/usage/base.py", line 193, in get_limits
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     self.get_neutron_limits()
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/usage/base.py", line 151, in get_neutron_limits
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     api.neutron.is_security_group_extension_supported(self.request)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/api/neutron.py", line 861, in is_security_group_extension_supported
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     return is_extension_supported(request, 'security-group')
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/utils/memoized.py", line 90, in wrapped
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     value = cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/api/neutron.py", line 841, in is_extension_supported
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     extensions = list_extensions(request)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/horizon/utils/memoized.py", line 90, in wrapped
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     value = cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi/../../openstack_dashboard/api/neutron.py", line 832, in list_extensions
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     extensions_list = neutronclient(request).list_extensions()
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 111, in with_params
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     ret = self.function(instance, *args, **kwargs)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 294, in list_extensions
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     return self.get(self.extensions_path, params=_params)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 1236, in get
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     headers=headers, params=params)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 1236, in get
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     headers=headers, params=params)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 1221, in retry_request
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     headers=headers, params=params)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 1164, in do_request
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     self._handle_fault_response(status_code, replybody)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 1134, in _handle_fault_response
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     exception_handler_v20(status_code, des_error_body)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 91, in exception_handler_v20
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]     message=message)
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error] NeutronClientException:
>
> ## 503 Service Unavailable
>
> [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error] No server is available to handle this request.
>   [Thu Jul 28 23:15:02 2016] [error]

This is the output when i checked if a neutron server was running on port:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9696            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

And on this is the neutron server log file(There is not a request from horizon app):

> 2016-07-28 16:48:01.5     INFO [neutron.common.config] Config paste file: /etc/neutron/api-paste.ini
>   2016-07-28 16:48:05.168     INFO [neutron.manager] Loading core plugin: neutron_plugin_contrail.plugins.opencontrail.contrail_plugin.NeutronPluginContrailCoreV2
>   2016-07-28 16:48:06.252     INFO [neutron.manager] Service L3_ROUTER_NAT is supported by the core plugin
>   2016-07-28 16:48:06.252     INFO [neutron.manager] Loading Plugin: neutron_plugin_contrail.plugins.opencontrail.loadbalancer.plugin.LoadBalancerPlugin
>   2016-07-28 16:48:06.506     INFO [urllib3.connectionpool] Starting new HTTP connection (1): 172.16.12.22

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the contrail plugin is running fine (since Contrail web-UI works), but neutron-server is not.

Are the neutron commands working fine? (Ex : neutron net-list/net-create etc. ? )

Is the 'keystone catalog' command showing the right neutron service details ?

Comment: When i use "neutron net-list/net-create" the consoler answer is "unsupported locale setting"

Comment: I fix the locale problem then When i use "neutron net-list" the consoler answer is You must provide a username via either --os-username or env[OS_USERNAME]

Comment: I fix de the problem of the keystone so the response to the command "neutron net-list"   is 
<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>

Comment: Check if the neutron-server is listening and is accepting requests. neutron --verbose net-list should help you figure it out